# Downloading or moving a directory in SFTP? -r gives an illegal argument

Tags: linux, sftp

I have a folder inside of my sftp server that I want to either download or move.  When I try to rename it (to move it), I get the following error -

```
Couldn't rename file "/my/directory/<directory>" to "/my/directory/path/../directory/newname": Failure
```

Passing in a -r doesnt work either -

```
get: Invalid flag -r
```

How can I either download or move these directories without the -r command?  I do not have the ability to upgrade sftp.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I like to use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) with wine, but since it's not the case try to use this command from http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp and check if it works.

```
rename oldpath newpath
```

PS: You can't use mv to do that

Comment: rename /some/old/path /some/new/path/
Couldn't rename file "/some/old/path" to "/some/new/path": Failure

Comment: Does your user has the necessary permission?

Answer (score 0):

download or move?

```
 get -r remote_directory
```

downloads the directory to ur machine.

```
 rename bla blub
```

does the renaming

Comment: which sftp version are you using?
did you check 'man sftp' and searched for get/download?
search with '/<word>'